# Not able to copy collection from mongoDB.I am using Studio3T.Collection size more than 16 mb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, robo3t

I am getting this error when i copied that collection:

> Error : bson length does not match what we found in object with
>   unknown_id.

What can I use to copy that collection?

Comment: Please edit the question in order to show the code which used in your trial.

Answer (score 3):

`copyTo()` id deprecated.
You can use aggregate:

```
db.fromCollection.aggregate([ { $match: {} }, { $out: "toCollection" } ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `copyTo()` function to copy your collection from mongo shell.

```
db.users.copyTo('newcollectionname')
```

If the specified collection name does not already exists, it will create a new collection in the same database.

> NOTE: This method is deprecated since version 3.0

And if you wish to move your collection to some other database, you can use mongodump & mongorestore combination to achieve the same.

For example,

```
mongodump -d db_name -c collection_name

mongorestore -d other_db_name -c other_collection_name dump/db_name/collection_name.bson
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant do this in mongo shell (robomongo for u) u must do it in CMD this url help me alot , see export and import part

visit :http://o7planning.org/en/10279/importing-and-exporting-mongodb-database#a66762